# How can we manipulate std class in php?

Tags: php, arrays, class, std

Is it possible to add elements to stdclasses like we do for arrays?

```
Array (
  [0] => item 1
  [1] => item 2
)

Stdclass (
  [0] => item 1
  [1] => item 2
)
```

Is it generally harder to manipulate objects as compared to arrays? Since we have lots of array functions to make use of etc.

Comment: Stdclass is the empty class, like Object in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can add new elements...

```
$Object = new StdClass();
$Object->item1 = 1;
$Object->item2 = 2;
```

If you want to iterate object as array you should use PHP SPL [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) or [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php).

Also you can use typecasting to move from array to object and back...

```
$array = array('item1', 'item2');
$Object = (object)$array;
var_dump($object);
$array = (array)$Object;
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not numerically indexed.

```
  $a = new stdclass();
  $a->foo = 'item 1';
  $a->bar = 'item 2';
  $a->goobar = array('item1', 'item2');
  var_dump($a);
```

If you want more complex scenarios, look at [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) and [ArrayObject](http://php.net/ArrayObject).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php) states:

> Created by typecasting to object.

As such, you can cast back and forth between (array) and (object) to work stdClass instances with array functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's no harder to manipulate. All I would say is things like count and array_search don't work on an object.

Array and objects both have their benefits it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

http://php.net documentation will state what data types can be passed to what functions.