# add item to json with php

Tags: php, json

I'm confused, cannot add correctly new objects to the json object:

```
$old_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.json"), true);

$new_json = ' { "1" : "111", "2" : "222" } ';
$old_json[] = $new_json;

file_put_contents("file.json", stripslashes(json_encode($old_json)));
```

it will replace the old records with new records, but I want just to add new record. I want it to write new json file with below content:

```
[{"a":"aaa","b","bbb"},{"1":"111","2":"222"}]
```

Please tell me how to achieve the right results. Also please show me how I can access new json object after json_decode()

Thanks.

Comment: What's the `stripslashes` for? How does the original input look? Why not append as a normal array after decoding?

Comment: For one thing, you have an extra `)` in `file_put_contents("file.json", stripslashes(json_encode($old_json)));` at the end, unless it's part of another opening `function`?

Answer (score 1):

When a string is converted from `json` to a `php variable` with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), this process produces a `stdClass Object`. Simply put you wouldn't want to add to the object *(heres [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652659/add-properties-to-stdclass-object-from-another-object))*. Although you could [manipulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497221/how-can-we-manipulate-std-class-in-php) the `stdClass Object` and then reproduce a new `json` object.